# How to use min-width on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I can't for the life of me find out why `min-width` isn't working on mobile on my website. There is probably a really basic solution to this but I can't find anything.

Basically, I have an element with this CSS:

```
fullscreen {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

This works perfectly on desktop browsers, at all resolutions and aspect ratios, but it completely breaks down on mobile, although when I change `min-width` to `width`, it fills the screen perfectly on desktop and mobile.

And when I use `height` instead of `min-height`, it works as expected and I can position elements with `bottom` on mobile, but when using `min-height`, it uses some arbitrary position about midway up the screen. `max-width` and `max-height` seem to work correctly as well

What's even weirder to me is that using the mobile device "emulator" on Chrome, the results seem to be totally random, sometimes working, sometimes having that midway line at the same place as my actual phone, sometimes having it in a completely different place.

My phone consistently has the midway line at the same place.

I've seen a lot of people recommend the use of the meta viewport tag, and I'm pretty positive I have it implemented correctly:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
```

The ideal solution for me would be to simply replicate the same behaviour as I have on desktop on mobile, since my desktop site already works for all resolutions.

Thanks alot for your help, I've spent at least 3 hours trying to figure this one out!

EDIT: I've tried implementing the behaviour I want in JavaScript, and for some reason, it still doesn't want to work on mobile. Here is a test I made:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mobile fit test</title>
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0">

        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id = "fit" src = 'http://placehold.it/1000'>

        <script>
            var image = document.getElementById("fit");
            var image_width, image_height;

            window.onresize = function() {
                console.log(image_width, image_height);

                var width  = 1.0 / window.innerWidth * window.innerHeight / image_height * image_width;
                var height = 1.0;

                if (width < 1.0) {
                    width  = 1.0;
                    height = 1.0 / window.innerHeight * window.innerWidth / image_width * image_height;
                }

                width  *= window.innerWidth;
                height *= window.innerHeight;

                image.style.width  = width  + "px";
                image.style.height = height + "px";

                image.style.position = "absolute";

                image.style.left = window.innerWidth  / 2 - width  / 2 + "px";
                image.style.top  = window.innerHeight / 2 - height / 2 + "px";
            }

            document.body.onload = function() {
                image_width  = image.width;
                image_height = image.height;

                window.onresize();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With this, I can still zoom, `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` do not appear to be what they're supposed to be, and it still works perfectly with any resolution and the plugin that Mileta Dulovic suggested. This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

Your meta tag is looking as it should be. If you don't want the user to zoom page you can use this

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Okay so. Media query works like this

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
...
}
```

CSS will be applied only and only on screens that have `width >= 768px`. On the screens below, it won't be applied.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
...
}
```

CSS will be applied only and only on screens that have `width <= 768px`. On the screens above it won't be applied.

If I understand your question good you have a problem when you use `min-width` with the media query. That is because you never tell it what to do on smaller screens.

Also, don't put too much faith in Chrome's mobile view. It is not good in most cases.. Rather install [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-web-design-tes/bdpelkpfhjfiacjeobkhlkkgaphbobea) for Chrome that helps you with that.

Comment: "install plugin for Chrome that helps you with that" that's very nice to know, thanks. "you have problem when you use min-width with media query" not exactly. I have a problem with the CSS property not working as it does on desktop. And I may be misunderstanding something here, but my site does work on mobile resolutions when running on desktop, just not when running on an actual phone. "If you don't want user to zoome page you can use this" that's also very nice to know. Thanks alot for your time!

Comment: do you have link of website so I can see the exact problem? Or if not could you update the question with screenshot?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've tried implementing what I want in JS and not in CSS, so now things should be clearer.